# Android studio run button malfunctioning

Tags: android-studio

I have this problem quite frequently on my Macbook Pro.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Open any project on Android studio
- Connect a mobile device to my computer via USB
- Click on the run button

At this stage, the green "run" button turns to grey but nothing goes on underneath. No *Gradle build running* or any similar notification. Any attempt to **Build project** or **Clean project** does not work. I also noticed that the Gradle pane at the right side of the screen is never visible every time this happens.

Usually, restarting my Android studio fixes this issue but I want to know if there is a permanent solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File and try Invalidate Cache/Restart. It will work.

Comment: I did this and the problem still re-occurred much later. This is not a long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried running it with an emulator or with a different device.
If it isn't working still, then please check if you have enabled USB debugging from the developer options of your phone,
Then once you connect the Physical device to the laptop or Desktop, a notification comes from the top of your mobile, showing USB Options, click on it and select USB for MIDI, then move your cursor a little bit and open Android Studio(If you haven't), To the left of the run button you will see the name of the Physical Device you have connected via USB and the Run button will also turn green.

If you face any issues connecting the device, check this Guide:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device?utm_source=android-studio#resolve-usb-issues

Comment: Well, I think this was an Android studio bug. I've not experienced the issue in a while. I don't think your suggestion would have been effective. The fact that restarting my Android studio fixes the issue means that it's not a problem from my device/emulator. Like I predicted, it was most likely an Android studio bug.

Comment: Then maybe you can try upgrading or downgrading your Android Studio Version, if the bug is there in a particular version then maybe it'll be fixed.